# How to download the image created using graphviz

Tags: python, graphviz

I have used Decision Tree to solve a problem. Then I have used graphviz to obtain the pictorial version of the decision tree.

```
import graphviz 
dot_data = tree.export_graphviz(clf, out_file=None) 
graph = graphviz.Source(dot_data) 
dot_data = tree.export_graphviz(clf, out_file=None, 
                            feature_names=f_name,   
                            class_names=['Topper', 'Not a topper'],  
                            filled=True, rounded=True,   
                            special_characters=True)  
graph = graphviz.Source(dot_data)
graph
```

I wish to download this tree generated in .png, .jpg, or any suitable format.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 4):

From digraph source create an image

```
digraph source - 
graph_data = "digraph G { ...... }"

fie_ext = 'png'
temp_img = 'temp_file'
my_graph = graphviz.Source(graph_data)
my_graph.render(temp_img,format=fie_ext, view=False)
```

render() method auto generate an image with temp_file.png extension in your current directory.

Comment: This worked, I additionally provided the directory since I was working on colab notebook, so that the image can be easily found in that directory

Answer (score 3):

To export dot file to image, you need module pydotplus.

```
from sklearn.tree import export_graphviz
from sklearn.externals.six import StringIO  
import pydotplus

dot_data = StringIO()
export_graphviz(clf, out_file=dot_data,  
                filled=True, rounded=True,
                special_characters=True,feature_names = feature_cols,class_names=['0','1'])
graph = pydotplus.graph_from_dot_data(dot_data.getvalue())  
graph.write_png('my_decision_tree.png')
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks!